# Not receiving the $message variable in view from a Laravel HTML Mailable (NON Markdown)

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5.5

I've read several similar questions related to this problem but all refer to Markdown mailables.

I'm trying to send inline images in the mailables but I haven't found a way to do it properly (Laravel 5.5).

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#inline-attachments) says this:

> ### Inline Attachments
>
> Embedding inline images into your emails is typically cumbersome; however, Laravel provides a convenient way to attach images to your emails and retrieving the appropriate `CID`. To embed an inline image, use the `embed` method on the `$message` variable within your email template. Laravel automatically makes the `$message` variable available to all of your email templates, so you don't need to worry about passing it in manually:
>
> ```php
> <body>
>     Here is an image:
>
>     <img src="{{ $message->embed($pathToFile) }}">
> </body>
> ```

But, when doing that I receive this error:

> Undefined variable: message (View: /path/to/project/resources/views/mails/new_user_welcome.blade.php)

I know that this has a limitation when using a **Markdown** message but **I'm not using one**.

---

This are the related files:

#### Mail/NewUserWelcomeEmail.php

```php
class NewUserWelcomeEmail extends Mailable
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mails.new_user_welcome');
    }
}
```

#### Resources/views/mails/new_user_welcome.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.mail')

@section('content')

    <img src="{{ $message->embed(url("storage/images/inline_image.png")) }}" 
    alt="An inline image" />

@endsection
```

#### App/Http/Controllers/UserController.php

```php
public function register(NewUserRequest $request)
{
    // some code

    Mail::to($user)->send(new NewUserWelcomeEmail($user));

    return 'done';
}
```

Comment: try to pass messages with contstruct.

Comment: Hello @AliÖzen, how do I do that?

Comment: Perhaps it fails somewhere else, because it should work like this..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, to be honest, I haven't found a way to make this work properly. I mean, as it stands, this should work. Maybe is my Laravel installation (?)..

Anyway, I did make it work with a workaround.

**1)** Using Eduardokum' [Laravel Mail Auto Embed](https://github.com/eduardokum/laravel-mail-auto-embed) package, this basically generate a *CID* for each of your media assets.

But after adding this package this didn't work as expected.. so I:

**2)** change the way I was referencing my assets, from this:

```php
   <img src="{{ url('storage/inline_image.png') }}" />
```

To this:

```php
   <img src="{{ asset('storage/inline_image.png') }}" />
```

Now it works.

Comment: for my personal reference, it would be great, to know, if it worked using `asset(...` without any additional packages?

Comment: @bart no, it didn't work. The original problem wasn't the way I referenced assets but the `$message` variable. Sadly, I haven't found a way to make it worked. And yes, I try what (I assume) you are suggesting but as I said, it  didn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

In my case (**Larvel 5.5**), I've managed, to modify header logo, in both **html and markdown**.

**Laravel documentation**, although really great, could be better in this regard.

Anyway, follow these steps, and you should be fine...

1 - Publish mail templates via:

```html
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

so you can easily modify your mail source files.

2 - Modify `message.blade.php` in `resources/views/vendor/mail/html` with this:

```html
@slot('header')
    @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
        <img src="{{asset('assets/img/pathToYourImage...')}}">
    @endcomponent
@endslot
```

3 - All your emails should receive logo via CID from now.

**Note:**

In this example Laravel, automatically converts assets to CIDs, so you don't need to call `$message->embed(...` at all...

Please test extensively, with these html/markdown directories and blade directives going on. It is kinda tricky, but it definitely, does its magic...

Comment: My laravel 5.5 is not changing the URL for a CID id, it's just sending the url.

Comment: @DonViegues are you sure you are using `asset()` function? If that's the case.maybe you should try package suggested by HCK in this thread - Laravel Mail Auto Embed.. BTW I believe this is a bug, and I hope it was fixed in Laravel 5.6. Can you verify that?

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm using asset(), it seems that the package you said is the way to go. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use like this than it can be work other wise you don't use $message variable in mail blade

```php
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');
    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com'); 
});
```

if you don't want use this method than you can use like this

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-send-emails-in-laravel--cms-30046

it can be work like this.

Comment: The documentations says this: "Laravel automatically makes the `$message` variable available to all of your email templates" so it should be available.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the File Path Variable in your Mailable as public property -> example $pathToFile.

If you have the file path from outside of the mailable you can pass in with the constructor.

```php
class NewUserWelcomeEmail extends Mailable
{
    use SerializesModels;

    // Must be public    
    public $pathToFile;

    /**
    * Create a new message instance.
    */
    public function __construct(string $pathToFile)
    {
        $this->pathToFile= $pathToFile;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mails.new_user_welcome');
    }
}
```

Then it works as expected in your view like this:

```html
@extends('layouts.mail')

@section('content')

    <img src="{{ $message->embed(url($pathToFile)) }}" alt="An inline image" />

@endsection
```

Comment: The problem is the `$message` variable not the ones flagged as `public` in the `Mailable` class.

Comment: Don't worry, I solved the issue with a workaround.. I'll update it tomorrow. Thanks anyway, mate.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can **embed images in markdown Laravel mails** (used here to eg embed a logo):

app/Mail/Demo.php

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Swift_Image;

class Demo extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $image_logo_cid;

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {   
        // Generate a CID 
        $this->image_logo_cid = \Swift_DependencyContainer::getInstance()
            ->lookup('mime.idgenerator')
            ->generateId();

        return $this->withSwiftMessage(function (\Swift_Message $swift) {
            $image = Swift_Image::fromPath(resource_path('img/make-a-wish-logo-rev.gif'));
            $swift->embed($image->setId($this->image_logo_cid));
        })->subject('My awesome markdown mail with an embedded image')
            ->markdown('emails.demo');
    }
}
```

resources/views/emails/demo.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
    {{-- Just embedding this image in the content here --}}
    <img src="cid:{{ $image_logo_cid }}">
@endcomponent
```

**Alternatively** you could embed the mail::layout component and put the image in your **header**:

resources/views/emails/demo.blade.php

```
@component('mail::layout')
    {{-- Header --}}
    @slot('header')
        @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
            <img src="cid:{{ $image_logo_cid }}">
        @endcomponent
    @endslot

    {{-- Body --}}
    <!-- Body here -->

    {{-- Subcopy --}}
    @slot('subcopy')
        @component('mail::subcopy')
            <!-- subcopy here -->
        @endcomponent
    @endslot


    {{-- Footer --}}
    @slot('footer')
        @component('mail::footer')
            <!-- footer here -->
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

**Or if you always want this header** just edit the `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/header.blade.php` file (available after `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`). Then of course you need to create the CID/Image with every mailable as seen in the app/Mail/Demo.php (or have a base controller for that).

Comment: The question specifically states it is not about markdown msgs.